# How to call a char driver using the PCI API for Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, pci

I am writing a driver for an FPGA. The FPGA is connected by PCIe bus.

What I want to do is:

1. Create a driver to find the FPGA in the system. I am using the probe function in the PCI API for linux driver. I am able to perform the communication with the FPGA.
2. In this probe function I want to create char drivers. Can I launch the function init from a char driver in a probe function from the PCI API in Linux?

Comment: There is special API for that. There are plenty examples even on SO site, Just google it.

Comment: what API is that? I have not found anything. Could you give me any advices?